# zsh function only runs once

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm fairly new to zsh (oh-my-zsh) and i'm trying to write a custom theme.
I ran into a problem and reduced it to the following testcase

```
PROMPT='$RANDOM > '
```

works as expected, it produces a random number on each command.
But when using a function

```
PROMPT='$(my_random) > '

function my_random(){
    echo $RANDOM
}
```

it always returns the same number, even after `source ~/.zshrc` still the same number. only when i close the terminal window and open it again, i get a new number which stays the same for the complete session.

only when i do:

```
PROMPT='$RANDOM $(my_random) > '

function my_random(){
    echo $RANDOM
}
```

i get two random numbers as expected... any explanation for this behaviour?

btw, i'm using kde's konsole on a fresh arch install.

**Edit**

fwiw i found using /dev/urandom directly works well. I would still like to know whats going on.

```
function my_random() {
    echo $(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '0-9' | head -c5)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$()`-expansion happens in a subshell, and changes to `$RANDOM` in a subshell don’t affect the parent. From zshparam(1):

> The values of `RANDOM` form an intentionally-repeatable pseudo-random sequence; **subshells that reference `RANDOM` will result in identical pseudo-random values unless the value of `RANDOM` is referenced or seeded in the parent shell in between subshell invocations.**

You don’t need to turn to setting the prompt to reproduce it:

```
% echo $(echo $RANDOM)
17454
% echo $(echo $RANDOM)
17454
```

bash doesn’t share zsh’s behaviour here.

The annoying bit is that prompt expansion *also* happens in a subshell, so you can’t just fix this by referencing `$RANDOM` in, say, `precmd`. The best way I can find is to do it in an empty expansion:

```
PROMPT='${RANDOM##*}$(my_random) > '
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Nice trick there with the empty exapnsion. I think i will go with that. Thanks!

Comment: `precmd () { : $RANDOM; PS1="$(my_random) >"; }` should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

As said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40076764/13608595) by chepner, you can fix this by putting `: $RANDOM;` in your `precmd`. This causes the value of `$RANDOM` to be taken and a new one to be generated.

e.g.

```sh
precmd() {
   : $RANDOM;
   ...
}
```